# jQuery changeHash and back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, back-button

When I use this to change between pages, the address in address bar stays the same (which is required  so that if a user refreshes a page, he should be directed go to first page)

```
$.mobile.changePage( "confirm.html", {
transition: "slide",
changeHash: false
});
```

But now my back button does not work properly. How can I integrate this behavior to the back button so address in address bar still stays same but they can go back to previous page when they press back ?

Currently my back button is like this;

```
data-rel="back" class="button" data-role="none" data-transition="slideLeft"
```

Comment: Do you want to add this functionality to the browser's back button ?

Comment: no to: data-rel="back" class="button" data-role="none" data-transition="slideLeft"